# Subsystem ID for TSQL when creating a Proxy for a SQLAgent job step

Tags: sql-server

I have users who have the SQLAgentOperator role but not the SYSADMIN role. They can create SQLAgent jobs and set the job owner as 'sa.' These users can only modify their own jobs, but we want to give them permission to modify jobs owned by others in the instance without granting them the SYSADMIN role directly. How can I achieve this?

To solve this issue, I created a credential for an account with the SYSADMIN role. My plan was to add this proxy under the 'RUN AS' tab in the SQLAgent Job -> Steps -> Advanced section. However, I cannot find the proxy under the 'RUN AS' screen in SQLAgent Job -> Steps -> Advanced.

Which Subsystem ID for TransactSQL should I use when creating a proxy under SQLServer Agent Steps?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot.

Checkout message ID 14530 "The Transact-SQL subsystem cannot be executed under the context of a proxy account."